How to make functions having asynchronous operations get called in synchronous fashion?
I am not able to understand javascript asynchrnous/synchronous puzzle.
I am facing a scenario in which i have two functions , FunctionA and Function B and each has lot of code like validations and error messages and a call to DB somewhere in middle of their code.
My challenge is to call functionB only when functionA completes execvution including the DB api call. I have no use of any value returned from any of these functions just want to control as the api DB calls are conflicting if order not maintained.
 function async doSomething(){
    var result1 = await functionA();
    //Call below function only when everything completes in functionA()
    var result2 = await fucntionB();

    }

I am not able to control the calling of execution of function B, the success function function of DB call in funcA is called after functionB has been called which itselve has another api DB call.

the code you posted should work, await is used exactly for your requirements, waiting for an async function to complete before proceeding further.

you can test it with promises and setTimeout(), check this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/zo816q29/1/ (functionB in the example isn't even async, it's just to prove the system awaits for functionA to complete before calling functionB)

By "get called in synchronous fashion", you mean "sequentially"?

of course it should be async function instead of function async, and I think fucntionB should be functionB; assuming those are just typos

The use of await in the doSomething code you posted is fine. If functionB() is still getting called before functionA() is finished, then something is broken inside functionA() (e.g. not waiting for its database call) and the returned promise is fulfilled too early. If you need help with that, you need to post the actual code of functionA (at least the relevant parts, in particular the db api call, you may cut the validation stuff short).
